# Prevent left/right buttons from scrolling page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which contains slider. The slider allows navigating between pictures with left/right key arrows but if there is horizontal scroll on the page then the page is scrolled as well with left/right key arrows. Is there any way to prevent page scrolling but not the navigation between slides in the iframe.
The code looks like this:

```
if (e.keyCode === 39) {
  next();
}
if (e.keyCode === 37) {
  prev();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should apply `e.preventDefault();` in order to terminate the default behavior of an event.

Comment: This will prevent both scrolling on page and navigation in the iframe but I require only on page but not iframe

Comment: so you did not understand it at all. what this does is disabling the default behavior of the browser. in order to make the frame scroll you need to add next() and prev() into the same code where you fire e.preventDefault();

Comment: I understood well and did exactly the same as you wrote but the page is still scrolled.

Comment: The problem was that I was using keyup() which does not work with e.preventDefault().

Comment: i'd prefer keydown. sorry i did not mention it.

Answer (score 1):

some kind of

```
$(document).on("keypress", function () {
    if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
        return
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Should I target iframe and document separately?

Comment: You need the $(document).on("keypress") function on your outer document, and the other keypress function that you specified in iframe. Also iframe should be focused so keypress could work there